# Load css background before css file

Tags: html, css, background

EDIT: I ended up using the second solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255715/6278923) and It works wonderfully. Thanks everyone who helped me solve this issue

I have an image declared in a css file like `background:url()`. The css file is the 2nd thing on the page to load, but the image is the last thing. This image is the first thing people will see on the site, but it loads last. Is there any way to load this image as soon as the page starts loading?[image]

Edit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeDiv();
});
window.onresize = function(event) {
  resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
  vpw = $(window).width();
  vph = ($(window).height());
  $('#mainPic').css({
    'height': vph + 'px'
  });
  $('#mainPicContent').css({
    'height': vph + 'px'
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}
#mainPic {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  background: url(//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Tree_example_VIS.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #4a565d;
}
#mainPic::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: "";
}
.centerText {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.centerBtn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
  font-family: arial;
}
.centerBtn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(14, 143, 185) !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(134, 134, 134);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainPic" style="">
  <div id="mainPicContent" style="position:absolute;top:75px;left:0;right:0;cursor:default;">
    <div class="centerText">
      <div style="width:850px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
        <h1 style="margin:0;margin-bottom:20px;">Header</h1>
        <div style="width: 725px;height: 5px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;">
          <a class="centerBtn" style="float:left;margin-left:145px;" href="#">
            <p>Button</p>
          </a>
          <a class="centerBtn" style="float:right;margin-right:145px;" href="#">
            <p>Button</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell thats everything relavant to the picture - let me know if you need anything else

Edit 2: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdutt0na/)

Comment: Add that style declaration in your head section before adding any external css file

Comment: You can reference your background image inline in your HTML file, as this will be looked at before loading your CSS document. Edit: was too slow!

Comment: Look closely, the image is loaded through **JavaScript** ? (`main.min.js`). Why?

Comment: @Aziz It seems to be loading through jquery - I have no idea why though

Comment: @MichaelMK Please provide basic HTML, your jQuery code and your CSS file. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us your code or create a fiddle, where we can reproduce your issue and see your research effort. Unless you do, we can only guess. --- Please see the help on how to post good questions!

Comment: @Arif just tried that - seemed to have no effect

Comment: @MichaelMK : Create and share a jsfiddle link, so that I can take a look there.

Comment: @MichaelMK : Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/arifahmedjoy/tdutt0na/2/